# How do I write a function that writes falling distance?

Tags: python, function, loops

Do I need to write `d = 1/2 gt^2` function inside a loop that goes from `1-10` for `1sec 16 for 2sec 64`?

```
def falling_distance( fallingTime ):
    distance = ( 1 / 2 ) * gravity * fallingTime ** 2 
    return distance

def main():
    print( "Time\tFalling Distance\n=========)
    for currentTime in range( 1,10 ):
        print( currentTime, "\t", format( falling Distance( currentTime ), ",2f" ) )

main():
```

This is what I have so far, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? BTW, do you notice an issue easily visible thanks to the syntax highlighting?

Comment: What is your output, what is your expected output, and how do those compare? If there's an error, what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Calculation *seems* correct, but need to fix those printing syntax errors.

Your main problem maybe not getting any division result, because the operands are not integers. In python 2.x we need to `import` division :

```
from __future__ import division

gravity = 9.8;

def falling_distance( fallingTime ):
    distance = ( 1 / 2 ) * gravity * fallingTime ** 2 
    return distance

def main():
    print( "Time\tFalling Distance\n=========")
    for currentTime in range( 1,10 ):
        print( currentTime, "\t{0:.2f}".format( falling_distance( currentTime ) ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
Time    Falling Distance
=========
1   4.90
2   19.60
3   44.10
4   78.40
5   122.50
6   176.40
7   240.10
8   313.60
9   396.90
```